# In cassandra , if 2 tables have same partition key ,how will the data get stored internally?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-cli, bigdata, nosql

I have 2 tables : A and B
with partition key 'Name'

If I have same names across both the tables 
Eg : Adam is present in Table A and B

1) Will both the rows hit the same partition? same node ?
2) What are the chances they can be in same node,same partition ? 
3)How will it get stored internally ?